# Google OAuth logic implementaion (404 not found, net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, google-oauth, passport.js

Our team is currently developing an app using react native (expo) and Express. The part I am responsible for is implementing Google OAuth login, and we are currently using passport.js for that.

The problem is when requesting the Approved redirect URI for Google User Credentials, it shows a 404 error.

```
'Cannot GET /login/auth/google/callback,' and in the console, there is a warning error 'Encountered an error loading page {"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "code": -2, "description": "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED", "loading": false, "target": 137, "title": "", "url": "https://(my ngrok domain)/login/auth/google/callback"}.'
```

This is my first time doing both React native and full-stack development, so I have reached here, StackOverflow, trying to solve it alone.

I wrote more code, but I left only the bare minimum due to these errors, with the rest commented out. If anyone knows why these errors are occurring and how they can be resolved, I would appreciate your response.

The following code is in question:

```
//App.js (react-native)
//...
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Web" component={LoginWeb} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
//...
```

```
//Login.js (react-native)
//...
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupBtn} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Web')}>
                        <View style={styles.btn}>
                            <Image 
                            source={require('../assets/google.png')}
                            style={styles.img}></Image>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
//...
```

```
//LoginWeb.js (react-native)
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const LoginWeb = () => {
    return(
        <WebView 
            source={{uri : 'https://(my ngrok domain)/login/auth/google/callback'}}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            style={styles.webBody} />
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    webBody: {
        flex : 1
    }
});

export default LoginWeb;
```

```
//index.js
//...
app.get('/login/auth/google',
  passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] }));

app.get('/login/auth/google/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
  });
//...
```

```
//passport.js
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

passport.use('google', new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: ID,
    clientSecret: KEY,
    callbackURL: "https://(my ngrok domain)/login/auth/google/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```